# How to make list-group scroll inside a div instead of wrapping it's height?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I have a div that looks like a receipt in my webpage, in that div dynamically will be added X items and it's full heigth should be 95% for graphic stuff, the issue is that when the div reach 95% of screen height and a new item is added the whole page become scrollable while i would to scroll only the list-group where items are added.

Here is how my layout looks like:

```js
            var prodotti = [
        { desc: "Prosciutto", qta: 2, prezzo: 2 },
        { desc: "Carne", qta: 1, prezzo: 15 },
        { desc: "Pomodori", qta: 6, prezzo: 3 },
        { desc: "Pandoro", qta: 5, prezzo: 22 },
        { desc: "Yougurt", qta: 3, prezzo: 5 },
      ];
      
      $(".totale").on("click", function () {
        $(".btn-finish").removeAttr("disabled");
        $(".list-group").append(
          $("<li>", {
            class: "list-group-item d-flex justify-content-between",
          }).append(
            $("<span>", { class: "desc" }).text(prodotti[0].desc),
            $("<span>", { class: "qta" }).text(prodotti[0].qta),
            $("<span>", { class: "prezzo" }).text(prodotti[0].prezzo)
          )
        );
      });
```

```css
html, body {
 height: 100%;
}

.scontrino {
  position: relative;
  background: #f8f7f5;
  max-height: 95%;
  padding: 1rem;
  font-size: 1.4rem;
}

.scontrino:after {
  content: " ";
  display: block;
  height: 24px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
}

.scontrino:after {
  bottom: -14px;
  background: linear-gradient(135deg, #fcfcfb 25%, transparent 25%), linear-gradient(225deg, #fcfcfb 25%, transparent 25%), linear-gradient(315deg, #00383e 25%, transparent 25%) -7px 0, linear-gradient(45deg, #00383e 25%, transparent 25%) -7px 0;
  background-size: 24px 24px;
  background-color: #dcdcdb;
}

.list-group-item {
  border-color: #fff;
  border-radius: 0.25rem;
  margin-bottom: 1rem;
  border-top-width: 1px !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" />

<div class="row h-100">
  <div class="col-5">
    <div class="scontrino">
      <h4>Il tuo carrello</h4>
      <hr />
      <ul class="list-group"></ul>
      <div class="alert alert-dark totale" role="alert">
        Totale
        <span class="price float-right">€0.00</span>
      </div>
      <div class="alert alert-success" role="alert">
        Fidelity
        <span class="float-right">001230013212</span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-7">
    STUFF
  </div>
</div>
```

To add items dynamically just press on dark-light button with class .totale

So how could i just make scrollable group-list when the .scontrini reached it's max height?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've added the following css to make the list-group to make it scrollable:

```
.list-group{
  overflow:scroll;
  -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
}
```

And then on page load i'm setting the height to list-group as the height of it's container minus static elements height in it like this:

```
  var height = $(".scontrino").height();
  $(".list-group").css("max-height", height - 250);
```

After that by setting height to .list-group dynamically it's working as it have to.